# Problema con While en Consulta de Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

buenas amigos espero puedan ayudarme, estoy guardando **datos suministrados por el usuario** en 2 tablas diferentes, al momento de guardar el segundo **dato** me arroja este mensaje **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

**Consulta para Verificar Existencia en la BD**

```
     $conta=0; 
    $instruccion="SELECT rifem FROM empresa WHERE rifem = '".$rif."'";// Seleccionamos que no Exita

        $instruccions="SELECT DISTINCT registrocliente.contactoc FROM proworld_cliente inner join registrocliente on(proworld_cliente.id_proworld='".$proworld."' AND proworld_cliente.id_cliente=registrocliente.id ) WHERE registrocliente.contactoc='".$comtact."'"; // Seleccionamos que no Exita

        $consulta=mysqli_query($con,$instruccion) or die ("Fallo la Consulta de Empresas");

        $consultas=mysqli_query($con,$instruccions) or die ("Fallo la Consulta de Cliente");

        $num_resultado=mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

        $num_resultados=mysqli_num_rows($consultas);

  if ($num_resultado==0){

            if ($num_resultados==0){
```

**Hago el primer Inserte en la primera Tabla:**

```
     $instruccion1= "INSERT INTO empresa(razonsocial,rifem,referencia,direccionem) value 
                                (UPPER('$razons'), '$rif', UPPER('$ref'), UPPER('$direcc'))";
     $consultaemp= mysqli_query($con,$instruccion1) or die ("Fallo al guardar la empresas");
```

**Despues de haber hecho ese insert debo buscar el ID de ese dato insertado previamente, realiazo el DO While para que no salga del Ciclo con un valor Vacio ya que si quito el DO WHILE la consulta sigue su curso y muchas veces no guarda todo los valores o no encuentra ese dato (ID)**

```
do{
    $instruccion2="SELECT id FROM empresa WHERE rifem = '".$rif."'";
    $consulta2=mysqli_query($con,$instruccion2);
        while($resul=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta2)){
                $idempresa=$resul[0];
        }
        if ($idempresa>0){$conta=1;}

}while ($conta<=0);
```

**segundo insert, en este caso necesito qeu el valor ( $idempresa ) sea mayor a 0 o bien reciba el dato del primer insert y previamente poder insertalo de nuevo**

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO registrocliente(contactoc,tipoc,fechainicioc,statusc,zonac,visibilidadc,notac,precioc,diascreditoc,diastoleranciac,limitecreditoc,id_pe,tipo_pe) VALUES ('$comtact', '$tipocl', '$fechaini', '$stac', '$zona', '$visi', UPPER('$nota'), '$precio','$diascre','$diasto','$limicre', '$idempresa', '$esempresa')";
```

***ASI SE VERIA MI CODIGO COMPLETO***

```
  $instruccion="SELECT rifem FROM empresa WHERE rifem = '".$rif."'";// Seleccionamos que no Exita
        $instruccions="SELECT DISTINCT registrocliente.contactoc FROM proworld_cliente inner join registrocliente on(proworld_cliente.id_proworld='".$proworld."' AND proworld_cliente.id_cliente=registrocliente.id ) WHERE registrocliente.contactoc='".$comtact."'"; // Seleccionamos que no Exita
        $consulta=mysqli_query($con,$instruccion) or die ("Fallo la Consulta de Empresas");
        $consultas=mysqli_query($con,$instruccions) or die ("Fallo la Consulta de Cliente");  
        $num_resultado=mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
        $num_resultados=mysqli_num_rows($consultas);

        if ($num_resultado==0){

            if ($num_resultados==0){

                $instruccion1= "INSERT INTO empresa(razonsocial,rifem,referencia,direccionem) value 
                                (UPPER('$razons'), '$rif', UPPER('$ref'), UPPER('$direcc'))";
                $consultaemp= mysqli_query($con,$instruccion1) or die ("Fallo al guardar la empresas");

                do{
                    $instruccion2="SELECT id FROM empresa WHERE rifem = '".$rif."'";
                    $consulta2=mysqli_query($con,$instruccion2);
                        while($resul=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta2)){
                             $idempresa=$resul[0];
                        }
                        if ($idempresa>0){$conta=1;}

                }while ($conta<=0); 

                $sql="INSERT INTO registrocliente(contactoc,tipoc,fechainicioc,statusc,zonac,visibilidadc,notac,precioc,diascreditoc,diastoleranciac,limitecreditoc,id_pe,tipo_pe) VALUES ('$comtact', '$tipocl', '$fechaini', '$stac', '$zona', '$visi', UPPER('$nota'), '$precio','$diascre','$diasto','$limicre', '$idempresa', '$esempresa')";
                $query_new_insert=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: Te sugerio uses echo o log de PHP para llevar una traza; depues del `if ($idempresa>0){$conta=1;}` colocarlo para saber que valor tiene `$idempresa` y `$conta`; asi saber si se cumple la condición que debe dar por finalizada la ejecucón, asi como los valores que estes pasando a fin de que armes externamente el SQL de SELECT para saber cual vuelve el ciclo infinito.

Comment: el valor **$idempresa** es 0 por lo tanto el **$conta** sigue en 0 y nunca sale del While, no entiendo porque no encuentra el resultado si es la misma consulta que se hace al inicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declara `$idempresa` fuera de los `if`s asignadole cero como valor inicial; quita el `do { [...] } while($conta>0);` *(practimente asumiendo que el `INSERT` previo sí se realizo sin fallo contrario ocurrirá el `or die{[...]}`)* procesa el `INSERT` que tienes despues del `do [...] while(...);` para obtener el `$idempresa` que se genero usa [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) ***(no olvides fijarte en las consideraciones para que funcione)***

```
$idempresa = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Dentro de las consideraciones que recuerdo para lo anterior es que(en tu caso) el campo `Id` de tu tabla `empresa` debe ser de tipo **autoincremento**.

Te sugiero previo a esto que te indico; hagas un `INSERT` a `empresa` (manualmente o mediante SQL que apliques) para constatar que `Id` se genera automáticamente con un valor esperado (es decir un valor distinto de NULL y mayor a 0 correctamente).

Comment: no tendria problemas al momento de que varias personas hagan uso de ese codigo (**inserten datos al mismo tiempoo**)

Comment: no me llamara el id equivocado??

Comment: He usado esa instrucción; y con operaciones concurrentes no he tenido problema en ello; MySQL toma como sesión por separado cada conexión (invocación del script de la conexión).

Comment: yo entiendo pefectament, pero tengo la duda si al momento de hacer 2 **INSERT** al mismo tiempo el mysqli_insert_id recoja el id correcto...

Comment: porque puede ser que inserte a **PEDRO** y **JUAN** al mismo tiempo desde 2 equipos distintos, al momento de obtener ese id como sabre q fue el de **PEDRO** si mysqli_insert_id ( recoge el ultimo)??

Comment: Si colocas más de 1 INSERT deberas usar mysqli_insert_id luego del que deseas obtener el ID generado; solo te devolvera el ID del más reciente INSERT. Si tienes varios INSERT y de cada uno obtener su ID, entonces deberás ejecutar el INSERT y seguido mysqli_insert_id asignado el valor a una variable para mantenerlo, asi sucesivamente.

Comment: Exelente , tengo varios INSERT y funciona